# c programming linked list sort names in alphabetical orders

Tags: c

The whole code is about asking the user to input the students' names and marks.All the other functions are good except wehn it comes to sorting the list.I am trying to create a function called sortlist() to arrange the names in the linked list in alphabetical order after the user has input the names.

```
/*void sortlist(){
    char t[25];
    struct Node*temp=head;
    struct Node*temp1=temp->next;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp->name,temp1->name)>0){
            strcpy(t,temp1->name);
            strcpy(temp1->name,temp->name);
            strcpy(temp->name,t);
        }temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

This is my sortlist() function and the programme crashes once I choose case 1. Is this not the way to implement it?

Here is the full code for the programme:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
    char name[100];
    float marks;
    struct Node* next; //next is a pointer that stores the address of the next 
    node
};
struct Node* head; //head is a pointer that stores the address of first node
void printMenu();     //function that prints the menu of the choices
void Print();         //function that prints the result of ALL the students
void Insert_marks();  //function that insert marks of the students
void Insert_names();  //function that insert the names of the students
void Delete();        //function that delete a particular student
void search();        //function that search ONE student and print his or 
                      //  her report
void SaveToFile();    //function that save the data entered in text file
void OpenFile();      //function that read data from the text file
void sortlist();

int main(){
    int choice,n;
    char strings[25];
    char words[25];
    head = NULL;  // the list is empty now

    do{
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            //Introduce the names of the students
            printf("enter the name: \n");
            scanf("%s",strings);
            Insert_names(strings);
            sortlist();
            break;
        case 2:
            // Delete the report for a particular student
            printf("enter a position");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            Delete(n);
            break;
        case 3:
            //Introduce marks for all the students
            Insert_marks();
            break;
        case 4:
            // print report for individual student
            printf("Enter the name:\n");
            scanf("%s",words);
            search(words);
             break;
        case 5:
            // print report for all the students
            printf("NO\tNames\t\tMarks\n");
            Print();
            break;
        case 6:
            //Save the data into a text file
            SaveToFile();
            break;
        case 7:
            // read the file
            OpenFile();
            break;
        }
    }while(choice!= 8);
}


void Insert_names(char strings[25]){
    struct Node*temp= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); //creating a 
                                                                 //    Node
    strcpy(temp->name,strings);
    temp->marks=-1;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
        return;
    }else{
        struct Node *p =head;
        while(p->next)
            p= p->next;
        p->next=temp;
     }
     printf("%s\t%s\n",temp->name,temp->next->name);
}

void Insert_marks(){
    float x;
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while(temp->marks != -1){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("enter the marks \n");
        scanf("%f",&x);
        temp->marks=x;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void Print(){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    int i=0;
    while(temp!= NULL){
        i+=1;
        printf("%d\t%s\t\t%f",i,temp->name,temp->marks);
        temp=temp->next;
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

void Delete(int n){
    struct Node* temp1 = head;
    if (n ==1){
        head = temp1-> next;
        free(temp1);
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n-2;i++)
        temp1 = temp1 ->next;
    struct Node* temp2= temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp2-> next;
    free(temp2);
}

void sortlist(){
    char t[25];
    struct Node*temp=head;
    struct Node*temp1=temp->next;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp->name,temp1->name)>0){
            strcpy(t,temp1->name);
            strcpy(temp1->name,temp->name);
            strcpy(temp->name,t);
        }
    }
}

void search(char words[25]){
    struct Node*temp = head;
    while(temp!= NULL){
        if(strcmpi(temp->name,words)==0){
            printf("%s\t%f\n",temp->name,temp->marks);
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void SaveToFile(){
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("studentreport.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp,"No\tName\t\tMarks\n");
    struct Node* temp = head;
    int i=0;
    while(temp!= NULL){
        i+=1;
        fprintf(fp,"%d\t%s\t\t%f",i,temp->name,temp->marks);
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void OpenFile(){
    FILE*fopen(),*fp;
    int c;
    fp = fopen("studentreport.txt","r");
    c = getc(fp);
    while(c != EOF){
        printf("%c",c);
        c=getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void printMenu(){
    printf("1.Introduce Student\n2.Remove student\n3.Introduce marks\n4.Print students report\n5.Print report for all students\n6.Save to file\n7.Retrieve data from file\n8.Exit\n");
}
```

Comment: Formatting/indentation;(

Comment: Is your space bar malfunctioning? Packing code without spaces makes it hard to read and understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is  here:

```
void sortlist(){
    char t[25];
    struct Node*temp=head;
    struct Node*temp1=temp->next;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp->name,temp1->name)>0){  // NOTICE: Dereference of temp1
            strcpy(t,temp1->name);
            strcpy(temp1->name,temp->name);
            strcpy(temp->name,t);
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

When there is only one element in the list `temp1` is NULL and the program crash when you do the string compare.

Maybe you wanted to do:

```
while(temp1!=NULL){
```

Further you also have a problem if the list is empty. This needs handling as well.

Besides that the logic seems wrong. `temp1` is always the same so there is no way this can sort the list.

In general I think a better approach would be to insert new elements in the correct position instead of having a sort function.